# Disqus comment system - change comments number before "load more" button

Tags: plugins, disqus

So tell me, if it's possible, using disqus Wordpress plugin, to change number of visible comments before "load more" button? I think default is 50, how could I change it to 20 or 10?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you ask at the plugin support forum which is in question , they better can tell you exactly.

Comment: thank you for your input, but I thought that it's so common need, that someone could know the asnwer